# Is there any way to check if the user share through my application with ONLY ME permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to check if my application's users are posting to wall (through my application) with ONLY ME permission.

Is there any way to make it?

My meaning is to application level (not feed).

Answer (score 1):

Only after the post is made you can check it’s privacy level.

For *only me* posts the privacy field in the post’s Graph API representation will look like this,

```
"privacy": {
  "description": "Only Me", 
  "value": "SELF"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I'm not sure how to get it trough graph api call.

Comment: `graph.facebook.com/{post-id}`

Comment: What, you do not know how to make Graph API calls from within your app?

Comment: Does this still work? Somehow it seems the "privacy" object is not showing up when querying published actions in open graph